# jinja2: reject a specific attribute from a dictionary

Tags: python, jinja2

I have the following dictionary:

```
d = {'name': 'Johnny', 'age': 23, '_id': 167, 'sport': 'golf'}
```

Using jinja2 I want to filter out (or reject) the `_id` key so I get the following dictionary (note this `_id` field is dynamic so I want to reject the key no matter what it's equal to):

```
{'name': 'Johnny', 'age': 23, 'sport': 'golf'}
```

I've tried using the built-in filters `reject` and `rejectattr` but it's not working as expected. This is what I've tried so far:

```
{{ d | rejectattr('_id') }}
# <generator object select_or_reject>
{{ d | rejectattr('_id', 'defined') }}
# <generator object select_or_reject>
{{ d | reject('_id', 'defined') }}
# <generator object select_or_reject>
```

Comment: I think you should put this processing into your Python code that calls jinja2 instead of inside your template.  That way your template doesn't have to know any of the business logic embedded in it.

Comment: `reject` and `rejectattr` reject the *objects* from an iterable depending on the attribute values they have, not the attributes themselves.

Comment: You are abusing power of ```rejectattr``` http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#rejectattr
If you don't want to render ```_id``` then use filter http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#filters

Comment: @jayprakashstar: How would you do this without `rejectattr`? Btw.: `rejectattr`is listed under "builtin filters": http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#builtin-filters :-)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe slightly late, but something along the lines of

```
{{ d.items() | rejectattr('0', 'equalto', '_id') | list }}
```

might help: It converts the dict into a list of tuples, and rejects entries depending on value of the first entry in each tuple. The final `|list` might not be necessary, depending on your use-case. It just converts the generator object created by `rejectattr` into a list again.

Comment: It is not gonna reject if first field is not '_id'

Comment: Which is the same as "It is gonna reject of the first field is '_id", which is what was asked for, isn't it?

Comment: it will reject whole object

Answer (score 1):

Here are two approaches. The first adapts [dasmy's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55813089/3787516) rejectattr-from-list-of-tuples approach to use the [dict global function](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#dict) rather than the [list filter](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#list). The second approach renders characters that will be interpreted as a dictionary by [ast.native_eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval), which is called by [NativeTemplate.render()](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/nativetypes/#jinja2.nativetypes.NativeTemplate.render). (Not only is the second approach already more verbose, but it may need to be expanded to handle all possible types.)

```py
from jinja2.nativetypes import NativeTemplate


def render_d(template):
    print(
        NativeTemplate(template).render(
            d={"name": "Johnny", "age": 23, "_id": 167, "sport": "golf"}
        )
    )


render_d("{{dict(d.items() | rejectattr(0, 'equalto', '_id'))}}")

render_d(
    """
    {
        {% for key, value in d.items() -%}
            {% if key != "_id" -%}
                {% if value is string -%}
                    "{{key}}": "{{value}}",
                {% else -%}
                    "{{key}}": {{value}},
                {% endif -%}
            {% endif -%}
        {% endfor -%}
    }
    """.strip()
)
```